# JavaScript closures and scoping: How to pass an outer scope variable to a callback function which is passed as an argument?

Tags: javascript, scope, callback, closures

My code is like this:

```
im.size((function(a, b) {
  console.log(b);
  console.log(im);
})(im));
```

The Object im has a function size, which expects a callback function. It passes the parameters a and b to the callback function. However I need to have the object im to be available within the callback. Therefore I pass it from the outside as an argument, however this "overwrites" the arguments a and b passed to the callback.

The output is:

> ```
> undefined 
> [My Object]
> ```

If I do:

```
im.size(function(a, b) {
  console.log(b);
  console.log(im);
});
```

The output is:

> ```
> 17
> [My object] // edited: was undefined before
> ```

How can I pass the im object to be available in the scope of the callback as well as getting the variables passed to the callback? A bit of explanation would also be nice.

**Edit:** Actually the outer scope is accessible in my callback example. Is this also true for asynchronous callbacks and WHY is the outer scope accessible this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: The second example should work too, giving that `im` is defined in that scope (deduced from the first example).

Comment: Can you post the complete code please, especially the place where you declare and initialise `im` (as well as everything else you do with that variable)?

Comment: You don't need to "pass" anything to a closure. The variables simply stay in scope.

Comment: @PM77-1 No, it has nothing to do with that. There's no mention of `this` in the question here.

Comment: Also the first example is not passing a callback to `size`, it passes the result of the IIFE (which is `undefined` in this case).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You are right actually dunno which type cause the wrong output before!! Sorry for that. Still I wonder WHY im is in the scope of the callback? Is this always true even for asynchronous callbacks?

Comment: If a variable is accessible at the scope a function is defined in, it will be accessible within that function too. You could have done `im.size(im);` to pass `im` to size (for example), so if you do `im.size(function() {})`, `im` will be accessible to that function as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: "*Is this also true for asynchronous callbacks*" - yes. "*WHY is the outer scope accessible this way?*" - that's just how it works - it's lexically in scope, so it is accessible. Other languages require you to explicitly state which variables you want to close over, JS doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The second example should work too, giving that im is defined in that scope (deduced from the first example).

If a variable is accessible at the scope a function is defined in, it will be accessible within that function too. You could have done `im.size(im);` to pass `im` to size (for example), so if you do `im.size(function() {})`, im will be accessible to that function as well.

> Is this also true for asynchronous callbacks?

Yes.

> WHY is the outer scope accessible this way?

That's just how it works - it's lexically in scope, so it is accessible. Other languages require you to explicitly state which variables you want to close over, JS doesn't.